# MySQL - get multiple rows in subquery

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:
 1. feeds
 2. photo_url

`feed_id  description       photo_id  feed_id  url 
  1         one               1         1       a 
  2         two               2         1       b 
  3         three             3         3       c 
                              4         3       d 
                              5         3       e`

Each Feed can have multiple photos (as above)

I am trying to query feeds along with list of corresponding urls

```
SELECT f.feed_id, f.description,
(SELECT p.url as url FROM photo_url p WHERE p.feed_id = f.feed_id) as photo_url
FROM feed f 
where f.feed_id = 1;
```

Currently I am getting this error:
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Actually I am expecting an output as:

```
[ {
    "feed_id": 1,
    "description": "one",
    "photo_url":[{
             "url":"a"
            },
            {
             "url":"b"
            }]
   }]
```

I tried with JOIN (LEFT, LEFT OUTER, INNER) but not getting desired results.
Is there any way to get result using nested query or should I loop a separate query for every row?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php):

```
SELECT f.feed_id, f.description, GROUP_CONCAT(p.url) as photo_url
FROM feed f
INNER JOIN photo_url as p ON p.feed_id = f.feed_id
WHERE f.feed_id = 1
GROUP BY f.feed_id;
```

Or, without the `WHERE f.feed_id = 1`:

```
SELECT f.feed_id, f.description, GROUP_CONCAT(p.url) as photo_url
FROM feed f
INNER JOIN photo_url as p ON p.feed_id = f.feed_id
GROUP BY f.feed_id;
```

Result is:

```
feed_id description photo_url
  1        one         a,b
  3       three        c,d,e
```

Check this [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93c133/4)